# VBA Pause and Resume and run in background

Tags: vbscript, notepad

I am extremely new to VBS so hoping someone can shed some advice for me. I am writing a VBS script via Notepad and i'm having problems with doing the following:

1. the script to pause and then resume after user has entered information requested via a inputbox
2. script to copy the data entered and then paste into the application window
3. When a script is running, to wait until the run has completed before executing the next script
4. After the user has entered their password, to hide the window and let it run in the background allowing the user to continue with other tasks

Script below:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Exec "app location"
Do Until Success = True
    Success = objShell.AppActivate("Application")
Loop
objshell.Sendkeys "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
objShell.SendKeys "*server name*"
objShell.SendKeys "{enter}"

wscript.sleep 100

strusername=inputbox("Enter your user name","User Name")
If strusername = "" Then
    Wscript.Quit
Else
    ObjShell.AppActivate("PuTTY Configuration")
    objshell.SendKeys "+INS", True
    objshell.SendKeys "{enter}"

strpassword=inputbox("Enter your Password","Password")
If strpassword = "" Then
    Wscript.Quit
Else

    ObjShell.AppActivate("PuTTY Configuration")
    objshell.SendKeys "+INS", True
    objshell.SendKeys "{enter}"
End if

*Resume the script*

ObjShell.Appactivate("application")
objShell.SendKeys "server name"
objShell.SendKeys "{enter}"

ObjShell.Appactivate("application")
objShell.SendKeys "*I need the password entered earlier to be copied and paste here*"
objShell.SendKeys "{enter}"

wscript.sleep 1000

ObjShell.Appactivate("*application*")
objShell.SendKeys "server name"
objShell.SendKeys "{enter}"

wscript.sleep 6000

and it keeps going until it's finished then does:

ObjShell.Appactivate("*application*")
objShell.SendKeys "exit"
objShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
objShell.SendKeys "exit"
objShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
objShell.SendKeys "exit"
objShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
```

I have also tried:

```
do while not wscript.StdIn.AtEndofLine
  input=input & wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
 Loop
do while not wscript.StdIn.AtEndofLine
  input=input & wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
 Loop
wscript.sleep 1000

ObjShell.Appactivate("*application*")
objShell.SendKeys "server name"
```

Comment: SendKeys is horrific and doomed to failure. If you want to start Putty via a script, just collect the server/password from the user using input boxes, then pass that as parameters to putty.exe like `c:\path\PUTTY.EXE -pw password user@server`. But then of course, the question is why would you do this in the first place?

Comment: I have about 20 vbs sendkeys scripts that I use at least once per minute, often more, for PuTTY. They work 99% of the time. Your script requires cscript to work because you are using console functions.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Sorry should've been more clear:
What I am trying to do is automate a process where a user can run this whole script in the background. The only interaction required is for the user to enter their username and password and then the rest will take care of itself.

I have been able to run the whole process from the script fine and just want to refine it to make it more efficient.

My problem is being able to get the user to enter a username and password then having the next command to run as oppose to using a "wscript.sleep" command.

Comment: The PuTTY suite includes commandline programs that have parameters for username and password.